# ASP Net FriendlyUrls appends existing url with new page url

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a Asp.Net windows form application. I have recently installed FriendlyUrls. As far as I navigate through page control the URL remains fine. But when I click on menu bar's  link. The page's URL is added in front of old URL.

e.g. if I am on page url: xyz.com/House/abc and then I click on menu's Society link (href="/Societies.aspx") then the url becomes xyz.com/house/abc/Societies

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: That looks to be correct. Remove the "/" in front of that href.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AlbertD.Kallal . I tried your suggestion but the problem is still there

Comment: Hum, I use the built in bootstrap and master page "default" menu system all the time. The URL's look like this:  href="~/Portal/MyProjects"  -- and I have friendly URL's turned on. You could try with the "~" in front but that's quite much the default you would see/have for existing menus.

Comment: Thanks for replying Albert. 

When I navigate to other pages e.g. from Home to /Societies/Blocks/Houses page, the URL remains fine. But if I click on Menu item Societies..................The url becomes /Societies/Blocks/Societies

on same page /Societies/Blocks/Houses page, if I click Menu item Home..............The url becomes /Societies/Blocks/Home

All this is happening on my machine. On launched website, I had to use complete URL for all menu items e.g. for Home page I used <a href:"https://www.foobar.com/

Comment: Ok, I going to suggest you clear your browser cache. The browser remembers URL's, and if you flip or change to friendly URL's, then you will go 100% nutty with issues until such time you clear out the cache - might not be the issue, but I blown out a whole afternoon due to this issue. Clear the browser history and cache - try again. (yes, I really am suggesting this!!!)

Comment: Hey @AlbertD.Kallal - I did just that. but the problem persisted. So to overcome this I updated the <a> tags of menu items with complete URLs on live website as they were very few. Now its working fine